# ARM Assembly optimization

Tags: assembly, optimization, arm

My goal is to write a quicksort ARM assembly code that is executed in a minimum number of CPU cycles.

I tried to examined where delays occured using gem5(architecture simulator), and I found that branch instructions were the main reason for delays. In other words, the branch instructions lowered IPC(Instructions Per Clock).

Could you help me alleviate this problem? (ex. changing order of instructions..)

Thanks!

```
qsort:  @ Takes three parameters:
        @   a:     Pointer to base of array a to be sorted (arrives in r0)
        @   left:  First of the range of indexes to sort (arrives in r1)
        @   right: One past last of range of indexes to sort (arrives in r2)
        @ This function destroys: r1, r2, r3, r5, r7
        stmfd   sp!, {r4, r6, lr}     @ Save r4 and r6 for caller
        mov     r6, r2                @ r6 <- right
  qsort_tailcall_entry:
        sub     r7, r6, r1            @ If right - left <= 1 (already sorted),
        cmp     r7, #1
        ldmlefd sp!, {r4, r6, pc}     @ Return, restoring r4 and r6
        ldr     r7, [r0, r1, asl #2]  @ r7 <- a[left], gets pivot element
        add     r2, r1, #1            @ l <- left + 1
        mov     r4, r6                @ r <- right
  partition_loop:
        ldr     r3, [r0, r2, asl #2]  @ r3 <- a[l]
        cmp     r3, r7                @ If a[l] <= pivot_element,
        addle   r2, r2, #1            @ ... increment l, and
        ble     partition_test        @ ... continue to next iteration.
        sub     r4, r4, #1            @ Otherwise, decrement r,
        ldr     r5, [r0, r4, asl #2]  @ ... and swap a[l] and a[r].
        str     r5, [r0, r2, asl #2]
        str     r3, [r0, r4, asl #2]
  partition_test:
        cmp     r2, r4                @ If l < r,
        blt     partition_loop        @ ... continue iterating.
  partition_finish:
        sub     r2, r2, #1            @ Decrement l
        ldr     r3, [r0, r2, asl #2]  @ Swap a[l] and pivot
        str     r3, [r0, r1, asl #2]
        str     r7, [r0, r2, asl #2]
        bl      qsort                 @ Call self recursively on left part,
                                      @  with args a (r0), left (r1), r (r2),
                                      @  also preserves r4 and r6
        mov     r1, r4
        b       qsort_tailcall_entry  @ Tail-call self on right part,
                                      @  with args a (r0), l (r1), right (r6)
```

Gem5 architecture simulator-CPU pipeline view
[image: Gem5 architecture simulator-CPU pipeline view]

Comment: If the problem is branches, the solution isn't to rearrange the instructions order, it is to eliminate the branches! Does your architecture support conditional moves? If I remember correctly, ARM has some pretty neat conditional-execution prefixes.

Comment: One common way to improve the speed of quicksort is to change to performing insertion sort for small array sizes (perhaps n=8 or smaller). I'd try that, and then measure again to find the new bottleneck.

Comment: If branches are causing delays then you could possibly remove some of the branches by using an optimization technique called loop unrolling (i.e. if the loop run 5-times, replace the branches with the same code 5-times). You could then re-arrange instruction in the loop to reduce RAW hazards if any.