# ARM Assembly: What is the difference between LDMFD and LDMLEFD?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm new to assembly language and there is a lot of info on what the LDMFD instruction does, but nothing on what the LDMLEFD instruction does. I thought they might be the same and that it is just a a different way to write it, but when I try interchanging them in my code they give different results. Here is one example of it being used in another stack overflow question. ([ARM Assembly optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225129/arm-assembly-optimization?rq=1)) I'm trying to understand how it is different from the regular LDMFD. Thanks

Comment: An easier to read use of the LDMLEFD instruction i found, its a pdf and the instruction is on slide 19. https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2002/CompDesig/lecture4.pdf

Answer (score 1):

`LDMLEFD` is a combination of the `LDM` (load multiple) operation, the `FD` (full descending) increment/decrement mode, and the `LE` (signed less than or equal to) condition code.  So, the same thing as `LDMFD`, but only executes in specific circumstances.  (I would have expected the condition code to be at the end rather than in the middle, but perhaps the assembler accepts it both ways.)

Comment: Ohhhh thanks so much! Yeah its a bit weird that its in the middle.

Comment: They do the same with the regular load/store commands (e.g. `strneh` means "store 16-bit value if the zero flag is not set, otherwise do nothing")